# How do I set the values of mapped selects so that they have duplicate values within a react app

Tags: reactjs

This is going to be a little vague as I am not able to post the code but I am trying to acheive the following:

I have a React UI where I have  component that to options: Type 1 and Type 2

[image]

When you select one of these, you then have you have a set of further options: a textfield and a Period select drop down.

[image]

And you can continiue to add these using the add button so that you can potentially have 3 rows.
What I'm trying to achieve is that if you select say "Day" in the first Select that option isn't available in any proceeding Select.  So you can basically only have of each type of Period. Like so:

[image]

At the moment I kind of have it half working where each Select only shows the correct options if they haven't been select befiore but I i start changing the values they all just disappear completely from the select.  The Select is being mapped over as part of array of rows.

Thanks(I appreciate this is hard to diagnose without code) so if anyone know of an online example of this it would be really helpful.  Thanks